# What tools I can use for find the answer to this problems?

Tags: number-theory

1. A natural number n has an even tens digit, if and only if, n leaves a remainder r < 10 when divided for 20.
2. Find all pairs of prime numbers p and q such that p^q - q^p =1

Comment: Please change the title. Also, have you searched already here? A full solution can also be found at "artofproblemsolving.com".

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.